# How to use ExoPlayer to play from server

Tags: java, android, streaming, exoplayer

I can't get my mind around how to use ExoPlayer, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8 but I can't get the player to work with my uri.

This is my code (same as in the video but with different uri) :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //player creation
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());

    //playerview binding with player
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    //telling what we want to play
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayertest"));

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4");

    Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);

    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

I can see the player and the controls but it does not play the video, I tried with various urls.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
private AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory factory;

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TrackSelector trackSelector;
private LoadControl loadControl;
private DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter;
private LoopingMediaSource loopingMediaSource;
private int lastSongIndex = 0;
private List<String> videoList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();
}

/**
 * this method initialized view controls.
 */
private void initView() {
    simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.amPrgbrLoading);

}


/**
 * this method play aut
 */
private void playMedia() {
    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(factory);
    loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    DefaultBandwidthMeter dBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "com.exoplayerdemo"), dBandwidthMeter);
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    // below line you can pass video url
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource("https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4"),
            dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

    loopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                lastSongIndex++;
                playMedia();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(error.getMessage())) {
                Log.d("ERROR::", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error::" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
            int latestSongIndex = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            if (latestSongIndex != lastSongIndex) {
                lastSongIndex = latestSongIndex;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMedia();
}

private void stopMedia() {
    simpleExoPlayer.stop();
    simpleExoPlayer.release();
}
}
```

xml.code.

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/smfvideoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:rewind_increment="30000"
    app:fastforward_increment="30000"
    app:use_controller="false"
    />
```

Comment: Your code seems kinda outdated and it has some errors that I dont know how to fix so I can't run it

Answer (score 0):

Exoplayer provides a demo player on GitHub:

- https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/demo-application.html

You can download this and replace one of the demo URL's with your own one.

This has the advantage that you are using the latest, hopefully widely used, approach.